# How to Reference an Object's Property by a String?

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have seen other questions asked on Stack Overflow about doing this, but I felt that they weren't answering the right question. They always answered how to access the name of an object with a string. However, I want to know a way to do this:

```
var obj = {
    property: "hello!"
}
console.log(obj."property");//want it to log hello!
```

Comment: `obj["property"]`

Answer (score -1):

You just access it like it's an array index, so:

```
console.log(obj["property"]);
```

Comment: "like it's an array index" - because arrays are objects will properties 0, 1, .... Since you can't do array.0, you use *bracket notation*